# How many Types of Asp.net web sites

Tags: asp.net

i Dont know how many types of asp.net websites.

ie. asp.net webiste types of categories.

Give me the deatiled Information.

eg: content based website....

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what is being asked here...not a clue...

Comment: There are 42 different types. (Also, what kind of website is *not* content-based?)

Comment: Whats the meaning of this question ?

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean how many websites are developed using ASP.NET?

Comment: NO... TYPES OF ASP.NET WEBSITES.

Comment: @user: Asking the same question that didn't make sense the first time is not going to help. Less so if you write it in all caps.

Comment: A website is a website, you need to describe how you are trying to categorise them, every website is its own 'type', you need to be specific, what are you trying to obtain?